# Shrieking crying 6 month old

Tags: infant, crying

So, our boy (one half of a set of 6 month old b/g twins) has just recently started his temper tantrums.  He used to be pretty mellow - with his sister having some medical issues where she was more intense.  Now seemingly out of nowhere he'll start crying, a low throaty howl type cry, or general shrieking.  He'll go from nothing to full intensity pretty fast. He doesn't look to be in pain.  Even though he's teething, if we walk in the room he calms down immediately. It seems to be a very loud call for attention.

In theory we wish we could just wait this out until he grew out of it.  In practice, he does share a room with his sister and wakes her often.  (Payback maybe; she did it to him when she came out of the hospital).  He also keeps himself awake, and we have a vicious cycle of cranky boy keeping himself awake, lack of sleep makes him (and us) cranky, then he keeps himself awake....

I know they change often at this age.  It's just that the things they like no longer work and we're not sure how to sooth him.  How common is this, and can we do anything?  If he was older we'd have the "this is not the way to get attention" talk, but he's 6 months...

Comment: You haven't said what works, except your presence. When does he cry? Whenever he's alone/wakes up/put down/etc.? Is there a reason you don't pick him up (maybe you're trying to let him soothe himself)? More (and more, like your parenting philosophy) detail will help you get a more useful answer. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Ummmm....I don't believe a 6 month old CAN throw a "temper tantrum". Children under the age of 12 months of age don't throw "temper tantrums" under the terms usually understood in the toddler world. Do you feel like your 6 month old infant is being defiant? Is that what I'm understanding here? Do you honestly think a 6 month old infant is "getting you back" for anything?

Although your children are twins, they are individual human beings. Brand new individual human beings to be more specific and they are not yet capable of defiance or temper tantrums...they are also not capable of regulating emotion, fending for them selves, "self soothing" or verbalizing their needs.

That said, pick him up. Hold him, comfort him. 6 month old babies don't cry for no reason. Maybe it's not a physical reason but he is upset and this is his ONLY way of communicating to you. Is he gassy? Many infants this age have gas issues weather they're on formula or not.  Have you ever had gas pain? You'd cry like that too if that's the case...ouch!!!

To sum it up, my answer for you is, pick him up. He is not yet at the age where you would be "spoiling him" buy holding him too much...that's old school folk lore. He needs you: you are his sole source of security, safety and care.

I hope this helps.  Its important to remember that all children are different and there will always be rough days/weeks/months.  Take a break when you feel pressure building and remember to breathe, breathe, breathe.

Best of luck.

Answer (score -2):

Be strong ! If you’ve genuinely checked for clean diaper, signs of gas, he’s well rested, fed, etc. then he is likely just wanting your attention/for you to pick him up. It’s very important to recognize whether or not he is genuinely in need or just wanting you to hold him. If the latter is the case then be strong and don’t give in every time. It’s imperative for him to learn self soothing skills once this begins and that he cannot be held constantly. I’m not saying NVER soothe or hold him, but be mindful of the context. If it’s just a fit and it’s happening often enough to hinder your day to day activities, he needs to learn to self soothe (aka, cry it out). If you are consistent with this it will be a short lived stage and he will be able to content himself. If you are not consistent the problem will continue to grow worse and fits will get more out of hand when you reach a toddler age.